# Inverse operation to `PublicKeyFactory.CreateKey()`

Tags: c#, .net, bouncycastle

Using Bouncycastle with C#, what is the inverse operation to:

```
byte[] publicKey;
AsymmetricKeyParameter asymmetricKeyParameter = PublicKeyFactory.CreateKey(publicKey);
RsaKeyParameters rsaKeyParameters = (RsaKeyParameters)asymmetricKeyParameter;
```

I.e. I have a `RsaKeyParameters` object containing a public key and want to convert it to a byte array in such a way that I could feed it back in to `PublicKeyFactory.CreateKey()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverse operation for public keys should be:

```
byte[] publicKey = SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory.CreateSubjectPublicKeyInfo(rsaKeyParameters).GetDerEncoded();
```

That factory class is in the Org.BouncyCastle.X509 namespace.

For private keys, the corresponding factory classes are Org.BouncyCastle.Security.PrivateKeyFactory and Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs.PrivateKeyInfoFactory/EncryptedPrivateKeyInfoFactory.