# Given RSA public key of size 2048, how do I get its modulus and exponent using built-in .net core function(s) only?

Tags: c#, .net-core, cryptography

I have RSA public key of size 2048 bits (as shown below):

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAjAc8U25mMDj93zGs6lEm
5HUbb22tLpWF8z13Lc4tRqNZ1WCGemI6fOhN1r1dkYpfMWakRqiCDX72gKi37zRX
XJhYz9F8qUXCzGPdCWhr2Eywyl5YKsCV+wnHjRPL++aqBEMBTrKsxrPByGjDxpYW
I/DgPinUWkZbSeIOZ4JX7Ze3SPNKDbDvJ5Ls2qGuFymtnpxWHbvWbHW1JuT4oHAd
1AhYOIRhVTRN+AGIgwvM0kpOsNH4P8KwhVe2CD6Pz6+54ealf1SctrE/X2EohigO
aG4O2QtGGc/FxnzhdHpLpcXiYhA6EFll+D3DdU6Hb4iBMYiQQBlFnf/A6Evuix+L
dQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

Is there a way to get the key's modulus and exponent by using .net core (without writing any custom function)?

Comment: See this: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/32185#issuecomment-419658415

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The public key has a [X.509-PEM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29707204/9014097)-format. For .NET Core **3.0** there is a [built-in support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#cryptographic-key-importexport) with the [`ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.asymmetricalgorithm.importsubjectpublickeyinfo?view=netcore-3.0#System_Security_Cryptography_AsymmetricAlgorithm_ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo_System_ReadOnlySpan_System_Byte__System_Int32__)-method of the [`RSA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa?view=netcore-3.0)-class:

```
// publicKeyX509PEM: String containig the key-data
byte[] publicKeyX509DER = ConvertX509PemToDer(publicKeyX509PEM);
RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
rsa.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo(publicKeyX509DER, out _);
RSAParameters parameters = rsa.ExportParameters(false);

// get parameters.Exponent and parameters.Modulus
```

Note, that the `ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo`-method processes only the DER-format which is essentially the binary format of the PEM-format 
(for more details see [here](https://tls.mbed.org/kb/cryptography/asn1-key-structures-in-der-and-pem)). Thus, the PEM-format must first be converted into the DER-format, e.g. with

```
private static byte[] ConvertX509PemToDer(string pemContents)
{
    return Convert.FromBase64String(pemContents
        .TrimStart("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----".ToCharArray())
        .TrimEnd("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----".ToCharArray())
        .Replace("\r\n", ""));
}
```

Alternatively, OpenSSL can also be used for the [conversion](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/openssl-rsa.html):

```
openssl rsa -pubin -inform PEM -outform DER -in <path to pem-input-file> -out <path to der-output-file>
```

Comment: Maybe Microsoft can just copy your answer into its documentation ;)

Comment: Topaco: Once I get the file in DER format, can I use the built-in functions in .net core 2.2 to import?

Comment: @Raghu This is a new method from Core 3.0 that does not exist in [Core 2.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa?view=netcore-2.2). To my knowledge there is no built-in support in Core 2.2. This requires third-party libraries such as BouncyCastle, e.g. with the [`PublicKeyFactory.createKey`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159147/inverse-operation-to-publickeyfactory-createkey/)-method, or custom code, e.g. something like the [`PemKeyUtils.DecodeX509PublicKey`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49889680/9014097)-method.